# reshape wide into long while splitting

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr, melt

I am looking for reshaping:

```
  ID p2012 p2010 p2008 p2006 c2012 c2010 c2008 c2006
1  1   160   162   163   165  37.3  37.3  37.1  37.1
2  2   163   164   164   163   2.6   2.6   2.6   2.6
```

into:

```
    ID  year    p   c
1   1   2006    165 37.1
2   1   2008    164 37.1
3   1   2010    162 37.3
4   1   2012    160 37.3
5   2   2006    163 2.6
6   2   2008    163 2.6
7   2   2010    164 2.6
8   2   2012    163 2.6
```

I am new to R, have been trying around with `melt` and `dcast` functions, but there are just to many twists for me at this stage. Help would be much appreciated!

A `dput` of my df:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:2, p2012 = c(160L, 163L), p2010 = c(162L, 164L), p2008 = 163:164, p2006 = c(165L, 163L), c2012 = c(37.3, 2.6), c2010 = c(37.3, 2.6), c2008 = c(37.1, 2.6), c2006 = c(37.1, 2.6)), .Names = c("ID", "p2012", "p2010", "p2008", "p2006", "c2012", "c2010", "c2008", "c2006"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe you can make it a bit simpler for us to answer your question: Using `dput(yourDF)` R gives you code you can dump here that allows us to reconstruct your data within seconds within our installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to shadow's answer is to use the `reshape` function:

```
reshape(d, direction='long', varying=list(2:5, 6:9), v.names=c("p", "c"), idvar="ID", times=c(2012, 2010, 2008, 2006))
```

This assumes that you know the column indices of the `p` and `c` beforehand (or add additional code to figure them out). Furthermore, the times vector above could be found by using something similar to the `gsub` function of shadow.

Which way to use probably is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are marvelous! Both ways work for me.

Comment: In case you don't know the right indices , `list(grep('p',colnames(d)),grep('c',colnames(d)))`

Comment: thanks for the specification, I was able to `reshape` my original data.frame!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to `melt` the data first, then split the variable and the year and then `dcast` to your final `data.frame`.

```
require(reshape2)
# melt data.frame
dfmelt <- melt(df, id.vars="ID", variable.name="var.year")
# split "var.year" into new variables "var" and "year" 
dfmelt[, "var"] <- gsub("[0-9]", "", as.character(dfmelt[, "var.year"]))
dfmelt[, "year"] <- as.numeric(gsub("[a-z, A-Z]", "", as.character(dfmelt[, "var.year"])))
# cast to data with column for each var-name
dcast(dfmelt, ID+year~var, value.var="value")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *also* use the following solution from `tidyr`.  You don't actually need to use regular expressions, if "p" or "c" is always the first letter of the column names:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) # only loaded for the %>% operator

dat %>%
  gather(key,value,p2012:c2006) %>%
  separate(key,c("category","year"),1) %>%
  spread(category,value)
  ID year    c   p
1  1 2006 37.1 165
2  1 2008 37.1 163
3  1 2010 37.3 162
4  1 2012 37.3 160
5  2 2006  2.6 163
6  2 2008  2.6 164
7  2 2010  2.6 164
8  2 2012  2.6 163
```

Comment: yep, this also works. thx. `tidyr` & `dplyr` are nice, just used it for other data.